# PhantomJS PDF Capture Doesn't Pick Up Font Server Fonts

Tags: css, pdf, fonts, phantomjs, webfonts

I'm using PhantomJS to turn an html page into PDF.  This page uses fonts from cloud.typography.com.  Now the html page itself is fine, and if I manually print it to a PDF, that too is fine.  However, when I use PhantomJS to turn it to a PDF, the server fonts do not show up.

I researched this issue, and while I could find general issues involving fonts, I could find nothing on this specific case.  The closest thing I could find was a bug in which PhantomJS would use the fallback font even if the primary one was available, but removing the fallback font didn't fix the issue for me.

Is this a known bug? Did I do something wrong?  Do you know of any work-arounds?

Here's the (generic) html to PDF rendering script I'm using.  I'm parametizing the page on the command line:

```
var page    = require('webpage').create(),
     args   = require('system').args,
if ( args[2].split('.').pop() == 'pdf' ) { 
    page.viewportSize = { width:1920, height:1080 };
    page.paperSize = {
        width: '8.5in',
        height: '11in',
    };
}
page.open(args[1], render);
function render() {
   page.render(args[2]);
   phantom.exit();
}
```

Here's a relevant html snippet that points to the font server and the style sheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cloud.typography.com/7787052/625786/css/fonts.css" />
```

And here's a relevant section from print.css that references the fonts:

```
body {
  font-family: "Gotham SSm A", "Gotham SSm B", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
}
```

Comment: Maybe change the order of the two links?

Comment: Does it give you the same behavior when the fonts themselves are actually sitting on the server? (fonts loaded via `@fontface`)

Comment: @ArtjomB. Tried that, same results.

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki.  I'll have to see if we can actually download these fonts to our server.  But first, I'll try using font-face with src and see if this takes care of it.

Comment: What version of PhantomJS are you using?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22229492/3960969, and here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22229492/3960969. See if either of those help out.

Comment: I am reading up on examples of people who gave up trying to support their webfonts, because PhantomJS (1.x) is currently running on an older version of Webkit, which has issues loading in webfonts in PhantomJS.

Comment: @radivisual.  I'm using 1.9.7 on Linux.  I did check out URLs you provided (thanks), but they point to the same article.  I think this was one of the first articles I read.  I've also experimented with font-face (both as a URL to the font server and as an inline with the app-data) but to no avail.  I'll throw in a link back to the server with a format('woff') just in case...

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10592) and [this](https://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/detail?id=592)? Seems like the `woff` files can be particularly problematic.

Comment: @radiovisual.  Not promising :(.  There is a 1.9.8.  I might give that one a quick try, just in case.

Comment: 1.9.8 only solves the SSL issue (POODLE)

Comment: SVG fonts seem to work for some people.

Comment: Seems a popular workaround is to switch to [SlimerJS](http://slimerjs.org/) which apparently has a nearly identical API to Phantom, but won't give you any of these rendering issues. Other than that, people are saying that PhantomJS 2.x won't have any of these problems, but who knows when that will be released.

Comment: You can also try to wait before you render with `setTimeout(function(){page.render("page.pdf");phantom.exit();}, 2000);`

Comment: @ArtjomB. Unfortunately, this didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: @radiovisual: I'll try SlimerJS first.  If the API and semantics (other than the font handling) are identical, then this can be a potentially quick fix.  Failing that, I'll see if I can get a hold of SVG fonts.  I'll let you know the results!

Comment: @R.Barzell, did you ever get SlimerJS to render your fonts? I am going to use Slimer for an upcoming project and wanted to hear your results...

Comment: @radiovisual Unfortunately no.  The issue seems to be \@font-face, and not whether the fonts are internal.  Seems all the renderers I tried cannot cope with custom fonts defined in this way.  Also, I found other issues with SlimerJS.  I definitely would use PhantomJS instead -- if you have a choice.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback. I am going to be dealing with this in detail sometime soon, so if I learn anything useful, I will come report it here.

Comment: @radiovisual Thanks!  If you have access to custom font files in true type format, you could try mPDF.  According to the documentation, it can support those fonts, provided you add them to the folder and the configuration; however, I have not tried this myself. Also, on another thread on a similar subject, someone said there was as soon-to-be released product that can do this.  I can get the name/reference if you wish.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I will keep them in mind when its time to dig into this. If you get the name of the library to assist with this, I would be curious to hear what it is. Thanks again @R.Barzell!

Comment: @radiovisual no problem.  The upcoming product is called/from Callas and here's the thread that in which it was mentioned (you can find the user there if you need to contact him): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27320249/html-to-pdf-batch-mode-converter-that-respects-csss-font-face