# HTML to PDF Batch Mode Converter that Respects CSS's @font-face?

Tags: php, html, pdf, pdf-generation

*NOTES: My request covers software or libraries, hence why I'm posting here.  I also checked the similar threads here, but they asked for something subtly different.*

I have the following HTML page:

```
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font.css">
   <style>
      body {
        font-family: "Gotham SSm A";
        font-size: 22px;
      }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   SUMMARY
</body>
</html>
```

And the font definition in font.css (truncated for brevity):

```
@font-face { 
   font-family: "Gotham SSm A"; 
   src: url(data:font/truetype;base64,...) format('truetype'); 
   font-weight:700; 
   font-style:italic; 
}
```

The page shows up fine in the browser, and when printed to PDF from the browser, is rendered fine as well.  However, every utility I used to generate a PDF from server-side software (PHP) failed:

1. Wkhtmltopdf, PhantomJS and PrinceXML didn't show the correct font (the latter gave a warning about not parsing all the CSS rules).
2. SlimerJS failed to render, opened windows, and had unacceptable
   dependencies
3. pandoc only converts to LaTeX and requires different utilities (on
   Windows/Linux) to go to PDF.  What's more, it's LaTeX conversion
   (according to the online version I trie) messed up the fonts as
   well.

What are my alternatives?  I need this to...

```
1. Respect modern CSS (including @font-face).
2. Be available on Windows & Linux with similar output on both
3. Be offline (utility or library is fine)
4. Allow commercial use
5. Be cost effective (preferably free)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at **[PrinceXML](http://www.princxml.com/samples/acid2/)**.

It meets all your technical requirements. It is free for private use (I don't know pricing levels when used commercially).

Comment: Pricing is here: http://www.princexml.com/purchase/. Be aware that the free version adds a logo to the first page of the created PDF document.

Comment: Actually, PrinceXML didn't work; I referred to that package as "prince" in my original question, but have updated the wording.

Comment: **/1** If PrinceXML didn't work upon first try, and if it "messed up" the fonts, then ***(1)*** *either* your HTML+CSS isn't cleanly and unambiguously defining the fonts to use ***(2)*** *or* the fonts specified in your HTML+CSS are not available on the system you run PrinceXML on, ***(3)*** *or* PrinceXML was unable to find the required fonts on your system. -- (continued)

Comment: **2/** You can let PrinceXML scan a directory of font files and create an appropriate CSS file from it with this command: `prince --scanfonts /Library/Fonts/*.otf > myfonts.css`. Then copy the appropriate `@font-face` snippets from the resulting CSS file into your own code...

Comment: @R.Barzell: Also, you may want to try and ask in the PrinceXML forum: http://www.princexml.com/forum/ (the developer is very friendly and responsive).

Answer (score 1):

callas software (watch it, I'm affiliated with this company!) has a technology they have been working on called pdfChip which will do this perfectly. It's not free, but it will handle HTML + CSS + Javascript using a simple command-line tool. And it can generate good, print-ready PDF (including PDF/X, metadata, professional color spaces, bar codes and more...).

I can't point you to a URL yet as it's going to be released in January 2015, but send me a private message if you want to see whether it would work.

Comment: Could be an option, but this is one of those issues that we're working to retire prior to the new year.  Still, if your package gets a commercial release, it may be something we'd revisit at a later date.

Comment: I'll contact you too  :-)

Comment: You're both welcome :) I actually have what is likely going to be the release version available, we're mainly still working on documentation.