# PhantomJS 2.0 is slow

Tags: javascript, php, html, phantomjs, webpage-screenshot

I'm taking screenshots of HTML pages using PhantomJS and I've been using my code (see below) successfully for over a year. However, a while ago I found out that the version I use (1.9.8) doesn't support web fonts: [PhantomJS not rendering screenshots with webfonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22229491/phantomjs-not-rendering).
In an effort to solve this I installed PhantomJS 2.0.0. This solved the font issue, but also increased the loading time of my script considerably (note that my script is 100% the same for both):

**PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows)**: ~1,5 sec

**PhantomJS 2.0.0 (Windows)**: ~2,25 sec

Disabling web fonts includes resulted in a ~0,2 sec performance increase for both versions.

I also benchmarked http://google.com/:

**PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows)**: ~1,9 sec

**PhantomJS 2.0.0 (Windows)**: ~2,6 sec

So it's unlikely to be related to my HTML or the fact that I use local HTML files. Following this observation I did some research and found the following options that don't work for me:

- [PhantomJS not rendering screenshots with webfonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22229491/phantomjs-not-rendering-screenshots-with-webfonts) - removing `local('...')` from the `@font-face` is not an option since I load my fonts through Google
- https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13117 - compressing/decompressing both executables
- http://arunoda.me/blog/phantomjs-webfonts-build.html - sound perfect but I'm stuck with Windows while only Linux and OSX are offered

**TL;DR** Does anyone have any ideas on how I can improve PhantomJS 2.0.0 performance? Code improvements, PhantomJS tips, Windows builds (e.g. 1.9.x web font friendly) - all are welcome.

**Code**

Loading the font in the `<head>` tag of my local HTML file (looks fine when I open it in my browser):

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Calling the PhantomJS PHP helper function:

```
$output = Image::getPageImage($pathToLocalHTMLFile);
```

PhantomJS PHP helper function:

```
class Image {
    public static function getPageImage($page, $options = array(), $js = null) {
        // Prepare the page path when needed
        if (strpos($page, 'http') !== 0) $page = 'file:///' . $page;

        // Prepare the PhantomJS directory
        $phantomDir = DIR_LIB . 'phantomjs' . DIR_SEPARATOR;
        // Add the PhantomJS directory to the PATH
        addPath($phantomDir);

        // In case no Javascript processing file is given, use the default
        if (is_null($js)) $js = $phantomDir . 'phantom.js';

        // Prepare the PhantomJS call
        $exec = 'phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true ' . $js . ' ' . escapeshellarg($page);
        // Prepare the PhantomJS options
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            $exec .= ' ' . escapeshellarg($option);
        }

        // Call PhantomJS
        exec($exec, $output);// . ' 2>&1', $output, $errorMsg

        // Decode and return the image data
        return ($output ? base64_decode(reset($output)) : false);
    }
}
```

phantom.js in the PhantomJS directory:

```
args = require('system').args;
page = require('webpage').create();

if (typeof args[2] !== undefined) {
    page.viewportSize = {
        width: args[2],
        height: (typeof args[3] === undefined ? args[2] : args[3])
    };
}

page.open(args[1], function() {
    var width = page.evaluate(function() {
        return document.body.offsetWidth;
    });
    var height = page.evaluate(function() {
        return document.body.offsetHeight;
    });
    page.clipRect = {top: 0, left: 0, width: width, height: height};

    var base64 = page.renderBase64('png');
    console.log(base64);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

My server environment is Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard with IIS7.5 + FastCGI running PHP 5.4. Like I mentioned before - the only variable in my benchmarks is the PhantomJS version.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How do you measure the performance? PhantomJS has an excruciatingly long process startup time. I don't think you can improve anything. You can let a PhantomJS process running and send your tasks to it.

Comment: To make sure where the problem is, you can use the CasperJS I particularly like very much for my projects! Using CasperJS, you can use the following lines to see exactly what the request is taking about `casper.options.verbose = true;
casper.options.logLevel = "debug";`

Comment: I am also testing an upgrade to 2.1.1 but it appears to be x10 slower on linux than 1.9.7

Comment: Guys, did you solve this problem ?